# PHP Warning: Module 'ldap' & 'mysql' already loaded when running PHP at command line

Tags: command-line, php

I am getting the following errors:

```
PHP Warning:  Module 'ldap' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'mysql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

when running the following command at the command line:

```
php -c /etc/php.ini /path/to/script.php
```

`/etc/php.ini` is the same php.ini that shown in phpinfo().

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Were these two modules compiled into the PHP binary? If so, you can remove or comment out the two pertinent extension= lines in php.ini.

Comment: Excellent answer Brian.  I want to note that also on my Ubuntu system, there is an /etc/php5/conf.d which has ini files that load individual extensions.  I had loaded the mysql extension in the main /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini file then the ../conf.d/ directory was included and tried to load it again.